# Not able to align d-flex child elements in a horizontal way

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, flexbox

HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end" style= "height:19px">
    <div class="like-btn-svg p-2" id="idlike" style= "padding-top: 100px;"></div>
    <i class="fa fa-bookmark fa-2x p-2" style= "color: #0099CC;height:0px"></i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .like-btn-svg {
        /* temp value */
        width: 80px;
        height: 95px;
        /* temp value */
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background: url(https://abs.twimg.com/a/1446542199/img/t1/web_heart_animation.png) no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 0;
        cursor: pointer;
}
```

In the Image the heart("div" element with class ".like-btn-svg p-2") and bookmark("i" element with class "fa fa-bookmark fa-2x p-2") icons are not in straight horizontal line[(CLICK ME TO SEE THE IMAGE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQTGO.png)

My question is I want both those elements in horizontal line at the end(SOMEONE ANSWER PLEASEEEEEEEEE).

Comment: Are you using boostrap?

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap

Comment: Can you post the code in a fiddle. Because with the code you gave. Empty containers are appearing on my screen. There is nothing in them.

Comment: ok i will post.

Comment: @Soban    https://jsfiddle.net/cgh064r5/        GO to this

Comment: @Soban hi did  you checked it out brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the parent div add `align-items-center;` to align the children vertically in the div.
Then remove the `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` style from this .like-btn-svg.
should work fine.

Comment: the translate(-50%,-50%) is mainly used if you use position absolute to center an element and you want to reset the element's center at the center of the page rather than it's top which by default will start from the center.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xbzLvq7g/ go to this(updated one), it actually shifted the two chidren elemnts to the left

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1c6dxsmn/ check this one. I have wrapped the `i` icon with a div and also the `align-items-center` on parent div.

Comment: i checked ur code, its working, but t is not working in my project code (but working fine in jsfiddle)

Comment: Glad to have helped,